# Where to download old versions of IAR EW8051 Embedded Workbench

Tags: embedded

I'm working with **CC2530** and it required **IAR EW8051 Embedded Workbech** for compling.
But when i downloaded the lastest version of it (ver *10.40.1*) and opened the CC2530 examples' workspace, the IAR said that CC2530 is not supportted.

So where can I get the older version of it.
Acording to **CC2530** examples' dog, version *7.50* should make it.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking where to find compilers are off-topic. And in this case the answer is kind of obvious: from the compiler vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Call your IAR rep.  They'll be happy to help get the older versions of the tools.